# Delphi Prism - DataModule - Data binding

Tags: winforms, delphi, delphi-xe, datamodule

What is the equivalent for Datamodule in Delphi Prism XE?  How data binding is supported in Winform applications using Delphi Prism XE?

Comment: This is not really a Delphi Prism (Delphi .Net) question, but more a WinForms question. Or are you using WPF for your userinterface?

Answer (score 1):

About you first question

In .NET there is no such thing as a delphi [`Datamodule`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TDataModule).

Now about the data binding.

The data binding in .net between Winforms controls and a datasource is made using the [`DataBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx) property wich is present in most of the winforms visual controls.

read these articles for more info about this topic.

- [Data binding concepts in .NET windows forms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/databindingconcepts.aspx)
- [Data Binding in .NET / C# Windows Forms](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html)